# What permissions are needed to write a PID file in /var/run?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, root, pid

On Ubuntu:

```
touch: cannot touch `/var/run/test.pid': Permission denied
```

I am starting start-stop-daemon and like to write the PID file in /var/run
start-stop-daemon is run as my-program-user

```
/var/run setting is drwxr-xr-x  9 root  root
```

I like to avoid putting my-program-user in the root group.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

By default, you can only write to /var/run as a user with an effective user ID of 0 (ie as root).  This is for good reasons, so whatever you do, don't go and change the permissions of /var/run... Instead, as root, create a directory *under* /var/run:

`# mkdir /var/run/mydaemon`

Then change its ownership to the user/group under which you wish to run your process:

`# chown myuser:myuser /var/run/mydaemon`

Now specify to use /var/run/mydaemon rather than /var/run.

You can always test this by running a test as the user in question.

Comment: This worked fine for me but when I restarted my server then the `/var/run/mydaemon` directory was gone.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, /var/run is tmpfs by default on Ubuntu. Each time the server is started up the mkdir and chown command need to be re-run.

Comment: @Tim how about [edit]ing the answer and complete it?

Comment: If you're dealing with daemon then a clean solution would be to add the path /var/run/mydaemon to the systemd unit file as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/779648/221801). An easier hacky solution would be to add the mkdir and chown commands to the init.d script (if one exists)

Comment: A better extensive answer is here: https://superuser.com/a/1127720/71795 a wrong answer which seems very elegant is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174433. Summary: use either `/tmp` or `~`.

Comment: For systemd users see https://serverfault.com/questions/779634/create-a-directory-under-var-run-at-boot

Answer (score 17):

```
mkdir /var/run/mydaemon
chown myuser:myuser /var/run/mydaemon
```

this will not work, since it will be lost at the next reboot (`/var/run` is a tmpfs on Ubuntu).

The only feasible solution is to run mkdir and chmod as part of the startup scripts.

Comment: Yes, you are right! CentOS will remove the dir when next reboot too. I like to set pid file to "/tmp", or just add "mkdir -p /var/run/mydaemon" to mydaemon.service

Answer (score 4):

In systemd-managed distributions, such as Ubuntu, no permissions are needed, and none are desirable.

On such systems, by design, all non-interactive services that could possibly need such access are either launched from a root-owned process - or use a per-user runtime directory. All permission matters can and will be taken care of the manager service.

No system-wide program will ever write to `/run` directly, but instead have a writeable directory provisioned for then by the system manager, only the latter having the permission to do so. The relevant configuration in a `identifier.service` file reads

```
[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=identifier
```

Which results in, when started as a system service, a directory `/run/identifier` being created. Or, when started from a non-root user, a directory `/run/[UID]/identifier`. Both directories, by default, are setup such that the program launched in conjunction is able to write there, and communicated to the launched program by providing the environment variable `RUNTIME_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: Thank you this is what I've been looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. Create a directory /var/run/test/ and then change the permission of this directory to the same user as your program runs. " chown  /var/run/test/" . Now in your application  change the location of the PID file to /var/run/test/test.pid. This should get things working for you.

Answer (score 3):

What about using the "sticky" bit on /var/run ?

chmod +t /var/run ?

Probably mess up some other apps, but it seems like it would be another solution.

I'll stick with creating a separate /var/run folder for now, however.

Answer (score 2):

Entries in the `/etc/permissions` are permanent.  Make an entry there to make the ownership and permissions for a directory permanent.

Comment: Apparently, this file only exists on SuSE. Source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-is-the-meaning-of-etc-permissions-745793/#post3635817

Answer (score -8):

To avoid putting your program-user in the root group, allow others write access:

```
# chmod 757
```

Comment: Never do a chmod 757 on /var/run! This would cause a serious security problem

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  It would cause a potentially massive security problem

Comment: Even if we ignore the security problem, `chmod 757` will also only work until the next reboot. Sorry about creating a new answer, but there seems to be no way to reply to the other comment.

Comment: @michel, the author never said to do a `chmod` on `/var/run`. The author may have meant it for the application subdirectory. Not sure what all the fuss is about.