# Create a directory under /var/run at boot

Tags: linux, centos7, systemd, daemon, startup-scripts

I had a daemon that needed its own dir in `/var/run` for its PID file with write permission granted to the daemon's user.

I found I could create this dir with these commands:

`# mkdir /var/run/mydaemon`

Then I could change its ownership to the user/group under which I wished to run the process:

`# chown myuser:myuser /var/run/mydaemon`

But this dir would be GONE whenever I issue a reboot!  How do I get this dir to create every time the machine boots?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There are two alternatives to have systemd create directories under `/var/run` / `/run`.

Typically the easiest is to declare a **`RuntimeDirectory`** in the unit file of your service. Example:

```
RuntimeDirectory=foo
```

This will create `/var/run/foo` for a system unit. (Note: DO NOT provide a full path,  just the path under `/var/run`) For full docs please see [the appropriate entry in systemd.exec docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#RuntimeDirectory=).

For runtime directories that require more complex or different configuration or lifetime guarantees, use **`tmpfiles.d`** and
have your package drop a file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/mydaemon.conf` :

> ```
> #Type Path            Mode UID      GID    Age Argument
> d     /run/mydaemon   0755 myuser myuser   -   -
> ```

See [the full tmpfiles.d docs here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html).

Comment: I used the latter because the actual daemon uses the `systemd-sysv-generator` and I've had enough learning curves for the week.  Just that one .conf file and that one line.  Feelin good right now B-)

Comment: I've already had the latter defined in my `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/php7.3-fpm.conf` and `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/php7.2-fpm.conf` and it still doesn't create the `/run/php` directory.

Answer (score 7):

I created a service that would make the dir at start:

`vim /etc/systemd/system/mydaemon-helper.service`

**The contents of `/etc/systemd/system/mydaemon-helper.service`:**

```
[Unit]
Description=MyDaemon Helper Simple Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/mkdir /var/run/mydaemon
ExecStart=/usr/bin/chown myuser:myuser /var/run/mydaemon
Restart=on-abort


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I started this service:

`systemctl start mydaemon-helper`

`systemctl status mydaemon-helper`

**Output:**

```
[root@alpha etc]# systemctl status mydaemon-helper.service
● mydaemon-helper.service - MyDaemon Helper Simple Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mydaemon-helper.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

May 28 20:53:50 alpha systemd[1]: Starting MyDaemon Helper Simple Service...
May 28 20:53:50 alpha systemd[1]: Started MyDaemon Helper Simple Service.
```

Lastly I told the system to load it on startup:

`systemctl enable mydaemon-helper`

Comment: Ok, I guess I should have placed this in my question considering I'm such a noob.  I'm learning though--thanks to you guys!

Comment: No, creating an answer was the right thing to do, so people can comment on it and also so it doesn't clutter up your question.    Answering your own questions is explicitly encouraged on SO.

And your answer isn't wrong either, it's just that there are much better ways of doing this, so IMO you shouldn't have been downvoted.   It shouldn't be upvoted either.  :)

Comment: While `RuntimeDirectory` is a better way of doing this *now*, I ran into a server with an old version of systemd (208) where that directive doesn't exist, so this answer is the only workaround.

Comment: This also still seems to be the way to do it if you need a directory created and owned by a different user than the service user, or for the directory to persist until reboot, or for the directory to be shared between multiple services.

Comment: Why does the ExecStartPre command need a `-` ?