# How to execute some command always after hard reboot (ubuntu server)?

Tags: ubuntu

I am facing an issue that everytime I hard restart my server (maybe went bananas due to out of memory, ddosed etc) supervisor fails to run.
And the reason for that is identified and simply /var/run/supervisor directory is deleted.

I learned that /var/run folders are deleted on hard reboot (via ec2 panel for instance force stop then start), so my humble question is:

How can I execute this `mkdir /var/run/supervisor` after every hard reboot ?
Where is the perfect place to add such logic. I guess it is not /etc/profile for sure

(the rest works fine, supervisor is configured as service + uses unix sock at var/run/supervisor/supervisor.sock)

My ubuntu version:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20 I would expect that supervisor is started as a systemd service unit.

In the service unit for supervisor you need to specify that the directory is created:  (the unit name might be different)

https://serverfault.com/a/779648 & https://serverfault.com/a/840999

```
sudo systemctl edit --full supervisor
```

and add a directive:

```
RuntimeDirectory=supervisor
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited `systemctl edit --full supervisord.service` because nothing was found with supervisor to ```[Unit]
Description=Supervisor daemon
Documentation=http://supervisord.org
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisord.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s
RuntimeDirectory=supervisor

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=supervisord.service
```

Comment: I chose your answer as solution , thank you. Next time hard reboot happens can verify if worked correctly