# Can a systemd unit create its working directory before startup?

Tags: systemd

I want the main command of the service (`ExecStart`) to run in a `WorkingDirectory` that may not exist on the first run of the service. I added a `mkdir` in the `ExecStartPre`, but it seems the mkdir itself is started in the same working directory that doesn't exists and fails. Also tried playing with the `+` and `-` flags, with no success so far.

Found a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209409/how-can-i-ensure-existence-of-the-workingdirectory-path-within-a-systemd-service) here, but no answer.

Another duplicate was [suggested](https://serverfault.com/questions/779634/create-a-directory-under-var-run-at-boot). The answers are basically:

- Create a helper unit that will create the directory for the main unit
- Create an entry in `tmpfiles.d`

Thanks for pointing these solutions. There are probably other solutions too. I was wondering if it was possible to create the directory from the service's configuration file, without having to rely on an external mechanism. This would make deployment easier for me. Sorry for not being specific enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a directory under /var/run at boot](https://serverfault.com/questions/779634/create-a-directory-under-var-run-at-boot)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thanks. While technically some of these solutions create the directory, I was looking to create it directly from the unit file (because of deployment considerations)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the meantime?

Comment: @gxx sorry for the delay, no solution yet, wasn't critical for me, but if you come across a solution please share !

Comment: @Antoine I might have an idea -- could you extend your question to describe what you're trying to do, specifically, AKA how your deployment looks like? This would allow me to get a rough idea if the mechanism I'm relying on nowadays might work for you as well.